# Google structured data on homepage doesn’t lead to Knowledge Graph info

Tags: seo, google-search, structured-data, knowledge-graph

We have a website and a few months ago I added the structured data code to its home page (as Google documentations guided me) but I still not get any changes in google search result.

This is what I have there:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "http://www.beatsense.com",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://www.beatsense.com?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "BeatSense",
  "url": "http://www.beatsense.com",
  "logo": "http://www.beatsense.com/static/images/logo.png",
  "email": "ilove@beatsense.com",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/beatsensecom",
    "https://twitter.com/beatsensecom",
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/beatsense",
    "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/beatsense",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/beatsense"
  ],
  "founders": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Oren Yakobi",
      "jobTitle": "Co Founder & CEO"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Shlomi Sasson",
      "jobTitle": "Co Founder & CTO"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

And I don't get the box with website/organization info, like this one for LinkedIn:

[image: Google Knowledge Graph example]

Does anyone have an idea why it happens?

Comment: Some of this is dependent upon strong branding signals for the site. If you have not created a Google+ profile for your business, you may need to consider it. As well, it helps to have a business listed in some of the various business listings to confirm you are a real business. This should happen in time especially if you do have a business listing in a yellow pages somewhere. Google does not want to take just your word for it. It wants confirmation of some sort. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont just get a box because you markup your website, you get one when and if Google think you are worthy. That means you will need lots of traffic.

I Googled beatsense and you already have several links under beatsnse.com so you are well on your way :) No searchbar yet tough

Comment: Can you cite a reliable source that says traffic affects this?

Comment: About the search, I put the SD tag for it but it's not appear in the results, is it also require a lot of traffic to be enabled by Google?

Answer (score 0):

Your Screenshot shows the data about LinkedIn in Google's Knowledge Graph.

From [Google](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9787176?hl=en)

> Google’s search results sometimes show information that comes from our Knowledge Graph, our database of billions of facts about people, places, and things. The Knowledge Graph allows us to answer factual questions such as “How tall is the Eiffel Tower?” or “Where were the 2016 Summer Olympics held.” Our goal with the Knowledge Graph is for our systems to discover and surface publicly known, factual information when it’s determined to be useful.

There's nothing *actionable* you can do to show up there, besides adding structured data like you've already done. And even then, that's just a hint.

The data in the Knowledge Graph comes from a variety of sources. The information it shows is well documented and consistent across all.

Most of that data shown in your example comes from Wikipedia. Linkedin doesn't even have structured data on it's home page, but if they *did*, and included additional information (that is permitted on panels), Google would probably display it in the panel. ​

Generally speaking, if it has a Wikipedia page, it's probably in the Knowledge Graph.

So historical people and events, places, actors/actresses and celebrities, large/publicly traded companies, music lyrics, movies, and other widely relevant public information.

The amount of traffic that the website belonging to an entity receives is not a factor.

However, the search volume of a named entity might be a good indication.

You're definitely on your way!

[image: beatsense search volume]